# Running EE across two servers - how to setup?

Tags: ee2, config

I am shifting to a two-server setup for running my site. This would mean one server handles MySQL and one handles web stuff. My understanding is all I need to do to make this function with EE (version 2.x) is to edit the database.php config file for EE on the server that handles the php to point to the IP of the MySQL server, but is there anything else I should do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct. The only thing that you will need to do is open up `system/expressionengine/config/database.php` and change the `hostname` `username` `password` and `database` and change the settings to match your new MySQL server credentials.